# Solving a system of four equations

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to run this:

```
Solve[{
  A + B == C + D, 
  Subscript[k, 1] (A - B) == Subscript[k, 2] (C - D), 
  C Exp[i Subscript[k, 2] d] + D Exp[-i Subscript[k, 2] d] == 
    G Exp[i Subscript[k, 3] d], 
  Subscript[k, 2] (C Exp[i Subscript[k, 2] d] - D Exp[-i Subscript[k, 2] d])}, 
  {A, B, C, D}, Reals]
```

But its saying its not a quantified system of equations and inequalities. Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: I see 4 equations and at least 9 unknowns (A, B, C, D, d, G, k1, k2, k3); the system is underdetermined.  Also note that it's bad practice to capitalize user-defined variables in Mathematica.

Comment: ...and to use needless subscripts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the premise of the question is flawed.

Comment: You cannot solve over the reals if you have symbolic parameters. That's what the message is indicating.

Comment: @Cassini Ok, thanks for the input. I'll switch to lower case a,b,c,d, and call the other d, d1. How can I solve in terms of the other variables, where i is the imaginary number? Thanks

Comment: You cannot include an `I` (imaginary number) if you specify the domain as `Reals`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - You can have symbolic parameters with a domain specification of `Reals`; however, all variables, parameters, and functions will be assumed to be real. And no complex value can be included (e.g., the imaginary number `I` cannot appear anywhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your last expression in the `List` input to `Solve` (i.e., `-D/E^(d*i*k[2]) + 
    C*E^(d*i*k[2]))*k[2]`) is neither an equation nor an inequality. To demonstrate a solution I have arbitrarily set the last expression equal to zero.

```
Format[k[n_]] := Subscript[k, n];

Solve[{A + B == C + D, (A - B)*k[1] == 
       (C - D)*k[2], 
     D/E^(d*i*k[2]) + 
         C*E^(d*i*k[2]) == E^(d*i*k[3])*
         G, (-D/E^(d*i*k[2]) + 
           C*E^(d*i*k[2]))*k[2] == 0}, {A, B, C, D}, Reals][[1]]
```

[image]